# WiFi: Mac can join, PC cannot

Tags: windows-10, wireless-router

### Short form:

My Mac and my PC can both join the WiFi network of my Netgear router.  But as of two days ago, the PC stopped connecting to the internet ("No Internet, secured").  Rebooting both the router and the PC did not help.

### Environment:

- Mac: Macbook Pro running MacOS Big Sur v11.1
- PC: Intel NUC running Windows 10 Pro v 21H1
- Router: Netgear R7000 running V1.0.11.116_10.2.100

### Details:

- My Intel NUC *can* connect to the Internet when I select a
  neighborhood WiFi network, resulting in a "Connected, secured"
  status.
- When selecting my AP's 2.4GHz or 5GHz networks, it does connect to the WiFi, but not through to the Internet.
- Reading the Netgear logs, I can see it hand out the DHCP address to the Intel NUC.
- Clicking "Troubleshoot" on the Intel NUC gives me the message: "Wi-Fi" doesn't have a valid IP configuration"

### Detection Details (hand copied since I cannot network to the Intel NUC):

```
Details about the network adapter diagnosis:

Network adapter Wi-Fi driver information:

  Description . . . . . . . . . .: Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz
  Manufacturer  . . . . . . . . .: Intel Corporation
  Provider: . . . . . . . . . . .: Microsoft
  Version:. . . . . . . . . . . .: 21.10.2.2
  Inf File Nmae . . . . . . . . .: C:\WINDOWS\INF\netwtw08.inf
  Inf File Date . . . . . . . . .: Saturday, December 7, 2019
  Section Name. . . . . . . . . .: Install_MCPIEX_GENM2CRF_9560_AC_2x2_HMC_WINT_64_AC
  Hardware ID . . . . . . . . . .: 
  Instance Status Flags . . . . .: 0x180200a
  Device Manager Status Code. . .: 0
  IfType. . . . . . . . . . . . .: 71
  Physical Media Type . . . . . .: 9
```

... further down:

```
  Profile: xxxx-5g (SSID name suppressed)
  SSID: xxxx-5g
  SSID length: 12
  Connection mode: Infra
  Security: Yes
  Set by group policy: No
  Connect even if network is not broadcasting: No
  Connectable: No
    Reason: 0x00028001
```

That last line looks suspicious.  Any insights about what "Reason: 0x00028001" signifies?

### update

As per @Tonny's suggestion, here's info from `ipconfig /all`, but with the Ethernet adapter sections ellided (since I'm doing all manual copying):

```
Windows IP Configuration

  Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : NUC-10
  Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . . . : 
  Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
  IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . . . : No
  WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . . . : No
  DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . . . : home

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

  Media State . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
  Connection-specific DNS Suffix. . . . : 
  Description . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
  Physical Address. . . . . . . . . . . : D0-C6-37-xx-xx-xx
  DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
  Autoconfiguration Enable. . . . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:

  Media State . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
  Connection-specific DNS Suffix. . . . : 
  Description . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
  Physical Address. . . . . . . . . . . : D2-C6-37-xx-xx-xx
  DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
  Autoconfiguration Enable. . . . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

  Connection-specific DNS Suffix. . . . : home
  Description . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160Mhz
  Physical Address. . . . . . . . . . . : D0-C6-37-xx-xx-xx
  DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
  Autoconfiguration Enable. . . . . . . : Yes
  Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . . . : fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%10(Preferred)
  IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.254.14(Preferred)
  Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
  ...
  Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.254.254
  DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.254.254
  ...
  DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.254.254 
  NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Interesting, and could be the problem: I've assigned my Intel NUC to have a fixed IP address of 192.168.1.101, but if I'm interpreting the above correctly, it thinks it's assigned to 192.168.254.14.  Is that the correct interpretation?

Comment: Please post ALL the relevant parts of the ipconfig /all output: You left the ip-address details of the Wifi adapter out and most likely the problem is there. Are you sure the ip AND dns settings are both set to DHCP ?

Comment: @Tonny: good suggestion.  And a LOT of manual typing :P -- standby.

Comment: With /24 mask these will be different networks. Make third IP address number the same.

Comment: Instead of error-prone manual typing, copy&paste the output to a text file and use a USB pendrive to transfer the data to a device with working internet connection. What IP address does your router use? If possible copy&paste all information the router shows about your PC

Answer (score 0):

The DHCP info clearly shows that your router is 192.168.254.254 and supplying DHCP, DNS and is the default gateway.
It supplies the 192.168.254.0/24 network to its clients.

If you want to do manual assignments of the ipv4 address you will have to use an address in the same range (and which is not part of the DHCP pool) or it won't work.
192.168.1.101 is certainly WRONG.

Why bother configuring it manually on the NUC at all anyway?
If you want to make sure which ip-address the NUC gets and that it stays the same all the time the proper way to do that is to log into the router and to configure its DHCP server to hand out the same address every time to the NUC.
(A so-called "static assignment" or "DHCP reservation".)
That also insures that the router knows what is given to the NUC and it won't try to assign that same ip-address to another DHCP client.

Comment: Turns out I'd already done that: the router has a static assignment for the NUC.  See following answer...

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, it appears this was a hardware problem: I noticed the NUC's WiFi adapter would connect briefly before quitting.

As a workaround, I got a USB WiFi b/g/n dongle and plugged it in.  Voila, reliable connection.

Move along, nothing to see here...